# How to add locale(with country) to font resources (Support Library v26)?

Tags: android, locale, android-resources, android-fonts

Google published the official font resources handling since support library v26 released:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

However, looks like I cannot add country qualifier for the font resources folder.

I have an app which has 3 languages: English, Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese.

And I tried to name my font folder under `res` this way:
`font`
`font-zh`
`font-zh_CN`
(I have also tried `font-zh-CN`)

*(Note that `zh` is the language, while `CN` is the country. With some more context for your information - In China we all use "Chinese", but there are Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese; Moreover, Hong Kong and Taiwan both use Traditional Chinese but the way we use them are a bit different. Most importantly, typefaces have separate files for Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese, due to the fact that they are quite different in their shapes.)*

But I cannot build the project. Android Studio keeps telling me that `font-zh_CN` (or `font-zh-CN`) is an invalid resource directory name.

This does not happen for my `values-zh_CN` folder (nor `values-zh-CN`).

**Question:**

How do you use different fonts for the **same language but different country**, using the new official method since API 26?

Comment: Maybe this can give some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344834/1306419 You can get the current locale and get the country part of it from the Locale. Accordingly set the font programatically.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in Table 2 at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Alternative Resources ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Thanks for your answer, in fact I already have alternatives, but I want to know a solution that works with support library v26's font handling.

Comment: @SeanBarbeau Oops, I believe I have tried `zh-rCN` before, but I guess  due to some other factors it did not work 4 months ago. Now I tried everything again and it works alright. Mind posting an answer for the bounty?

Comment: No worries, glad it worked. I just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for resource folder names is defined in Table 2 here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Alternative%20Resources

Specifically, try:

`font-zh-rCN`

Answer (score 1):

As @SeanBarbeau pointed out, the correct pattern should be `{language}-r{country}`.

I definitely have tried this 4 months ago before I asked this question, but at that time, I believe there are other factors which make it fail.

And therefore I would like to add some more info here, in the hope of helping more people who are in trouble.

#### How do I change language (and corresponding font) in-app

Short answer is by wrapping the context in `onAttachBaseContext` of a `BaseActivity`.
Specifically I followed the guide [here](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758).

But in order for everything to work, you need to make sure 2 things:

#### (1) Your font resources are located in a correctly qualified folder;

Which is answered already in this thread, and;

#### (2) You wrapped the context in a correct locale

I believe this was what I missed 4 months ago.

At that time I didn't know much about the format of a locale.
I think I kept using something like `new Locale("zh-CN")` or `new Locale("zh_CN")` or `new Locale("zh-rCN")`. All of these are wrong!

The best way to specify a locale is to use the built-in constants, e.g. `Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE`.

If you look into this constant, it is calling the method `createConstant("zh", "CN")`.
While `createConstant()` is a private method, I think it should be the same as `new Locale("zh", "CN")`; yet I still suggest using the constants.

So, at the end, your `ContextWrapper` should look like this:

```
public static Context wrap(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (locale == null) locale = Locale.ENGLISH; //Your default locale
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return context;
    }
}
```

The point here is to **directly pass a `Locale` object to the wrapper**, *which is different from most examples out there which used a `String`*.
While the conversion of preference (probably just a String) to Locale object is up to your implementation.