# Android textview font based on language

Tags: android, fonts, textview

Is there a general method for handling font like, if it is Chinese I use a custom font for it, if English then I fall back to the default font? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the default font for all TextViews in the app or want to be specific?

Comment: Just specific is ok

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents. You can use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library to change the custom font easily either for whole app or for specific `TextView` as well.

- If you want to do it for whole app, then one solution I can think of is:

  1. In your app you can listen to the [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) of [ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED).
  2. Inside the listener check to see whether the locale is `Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE` or `Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE`, then change the app's font.
- If you want to programatically change font of lets say partial text then you can use `CalligraphyTypefaceSpan` as mentioned [Multiple Typeface's per TextView / Spannables](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy#multiple-typefaces-per-textview--spannables) section:

  ```
  SpannableStringBuilder sBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
  sBuilder.append("Hello!") // Bold this
  .append("I use Calligraphy"); // Default TextView font.
  // Create the Typeface you want to apply to certain text
  CalligraphyTypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new 
  CalligraphyTypefaceSpan(TypefaceUtils.load(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"));
  // Apply typeface to the Spannable 0 - 6 "Hello!" This can of course by dynamic.
  sBuilder.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  setText(sBuilder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  ```

Hope it helps.

*P.S: I am not affiliated to the library in any way. I am a happy user of it.*

Comment: Thanks Shobhit. I checked the library you mentioned but seems not suited for my purpose.

My situation is if I have text like XX Hello YY, suppose XX and YY is Chinese, I want XX and YY to display in a Chinese font, while Hello display in another font that is suitable for English.

Comment: I see. The question wasn't clear in that respect. Please edit the question to update that. I've updated the answer. If you read [Multiple Typeface's per TextView / Spannables](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy#multiple-typefaces-per-textview--spannables) section of the github readme page, that seem to exactly do what you seem to be trying to achieve.