# Font resources for different Languages

Tags: android, locale, android-resources, android-fonts

I'm trying to use font resource directory and use different fonts in xml files in order to use them in preference. I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066720/how-to-add-localewith-country-to-font-resources-support-library-v26) but I couldn't solve the problem. I'm using support library v27 and I know it supports font in res instead of asset folder. Whenever I change the language of app it only uses just the font which is located in font-fa-rIR folder. I want application uses different fonts for different type of languages respectively. I have attached an image from res directory of application. Where is my problem? How can I solve it? Thank in advance.

**preference_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Font resource directory]

[image: Effect of font on English language, as you can see the numbers are still in Farsi which means it uses Farsi font]

[image: Effect of font on Farsi language]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be This Que Helps You

Ref: [Chnaging Locale It self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

```
Locale locale2 = new Locale("fr"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale2);
Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
config2.locale = locale2;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
    config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Font From Res

```
TextView tv_the = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
tv_the.setTypeface(face);
```

For More Info : [How to set custom font in .xml file instead of .java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472953/how-to-set-custom-font-in-xml-file-instead-of-java-file)

Comment: Thanks but I have a class which can change Locale even in runtime. I'm confused how to use fonts in res just same as layouts and other resources.

Comment: Thanks, It is a great idea to use modified TextView inside preference xml files. In this case, I don't need to use font resource directory. Thanks an ocean

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Changing Locale Itself is not fetching the font which is available in "font-fr" folder. On Restart of application it is taking that font, but not on runtime. How to do that

Comment: @user137021 may this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated